# randomly insert sequence of missing data (NAs)

Tags: r

An example "copied from mi package" simulate fake data

```
library(mi)
set.seed(100)
n <- 100
u1 <- rbinom(n, 1, .5)
v1 <- log(rnorm(n, 5, 1))
x1 <- u1*exp(v1)
u2 <- rbinom(n, 1, .5)
v2 <- log(rnorm(n, 5, 1))
x2 <- u2*exp(v2)
x3 <- rbinom(n, 1, prob=0.45)
x4 <- ordered(rep(seq(1, 5),100)[sample(1:n, n)])
x5 <- rep(letters[1:10],10)[sample(1:n, n)]
x6 <- trunc(runif(n, 1, 10))
x7 <- rnorm(n)
x8 <- factor(rep(seq(1,10),10)[sample(1:n, n)])
x9 <- runif(n, 0.1, .99)
x10 <- rpois(n, 4)
y <- x1 + x2 + x7 + x9 + rnorm(n)
fakedata <- cbind.data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10)

# randomly create missing values
dat <- mi:::.create.missing(fakedata, pct.mis=10)
```

Now `dat` is the new data with 10% of Random NAs inserted.

My question is how to control the number of NAs that will be inserted at a time in all the columns of the data without temparing the random nature of the insertion.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454265/r-randomly-insert-nas-into-dataframe-proportionaly/27454361#27454361) work well enough?

Comment: Thanks @r2evans the answers worked fine but i want to control the size of the NAs to impute.

Comment: By adjusting the `prob` argument to `sample`, you control how many `NA`s are inserted into the data. If you change the code in the other answer to instead use `prob = c(0.9, 0.1)`, would that accomplish your goal?

Comment: Thanks @r2evans no what i meant was that i want to control the length of the NAs at each place for each place NAs are inserted. i.e the same length of NAs to be inserted at each point say 5 NAs appearing consecutively.