# How to generate random missing values for a column in a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame as follows:

```
A   B   C
30  25  8
10  30  59
6   75  40
```

Then, how can I generate random missing values in column C as shown below using R programming language?

```
A   B   C
30  25  8
10  30  NA
6   75  40
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Randomly insert NAs into dataframe proportionaly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454265/randomly-insert-nas-into-dataframe-proportionaly) (in other words, does `df$C <- df$C[sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.8, 0.2), size = length(df$C), replace = TRUE)]` give you your desired outcome?)

Comment: Thank you so much jared_mamrot for helping me. I appreciate it.